# WSO2 ESB discards leading zero JSON

Tags: json, rest, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I am creating a Rest API using HTTP POST with JSON request body with following format:

```
{ "test":{"msisdn":"08182234566","amount":"10000"}}
```

I am going to use a msisdn value as argument of a `PayloadFactory` mediator using the JSON expression `$.test.msisdn`.

However value of msisdn is changed to 8182234566 without leading zero.

Following `messageFormatter` & `messageBuilder`, I use on WSO2 ESB axis2 config:

```
org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter
org.apache.axis2.json.JSONOMBuilder
```

How can I preserve leading zero on WSO2 ESB?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I had an equivalent bug and I exchange

```
org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter by org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamFormatter
```

and

```
org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBuilder by org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamBuilder
```

After that, all work and my Json wasn't change by wso2

Maybe this can help you